# What do brackets mean in a venn diagram

Tags: probability

[image]

So what does (16) mean? why is there bracket and how does this different than normal number?

Comment: ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯ . Such a subtlety doesn't look standard, therefore clarification should be up to the author of the book.

Comment: Impossible to answer... maybe the number of elements of the corresponding set. But if they are pages from a book, you have to search into the previous pages.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No i just got one page of venn diagrams. the previous page is about combination/permutation and has nothing to do with this

Comment: @SaucyO'Path i really just got that 16 in a brackets and 8. the question is find n(a u b), n(a n b), n(a|b)

Comment: $n$ ? It looks like probability... [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition) : $P(A|B)=P(A \cap B) / P(B)$.

Comment: Maybe useful : [Probability with Venn diagrams](https://www.bbc.com/bitesize/guides/z33rwxs/revision/5).